# Is 'rubyinstaller.org' the official website for ruby?

Tags: ruby, installation

I found two websites:

[rubyinstaller.org](https://rubyinstaller.org)

[ruby-lang.org](https://www.ruby-lang.org)

Which of them is the official website, or can I just download Ruby from any of them?

Comment: Well, did you even open the links? It all says there - what is the first one, and what is the second one...

Comment: go with ruby-lang.org

Comment: ruby-lang.org is the official one.

Answer (score 0):

ruby-lang.org is the official website. rubyinstaller.org provides an installer for windows.